# Neo4j - persons with mutual friends only

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4j using Cypher:

I need to find PersonB that has exact same friends as PersonA.

Example:
Paul knows Peter, Ana, and Mike and nobody else.
Find who else knows Peter, Ana, and Mike and nobody else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Please produce some input data, expected output and what you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @Fabio Lamanna, can you not interfere if you're not bringing anything useful to the conversation?  Two of your three "requests" are listed in my question.  Stackoverflow is for people to help and get help, and I'm glad Tezra has helped me.

Comment: I'm not interfering at all, just help you to follow the [Stackoverflow Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you should read before asking. I'm glad somebody made his own effort and solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the breakdown of how to do a query like this.

```
// Match side a
MATCH (n1:Person)--(m:Person)
WITH n1, COLLECT(m) as friends
// Match side b
MATCH (n2:Person)--(m:Person)
WITH n1, n2, friends as friends1, COLLECT(m) as friends2
// Filter out a-b same node or non identical friends lists.
WHERE n1<>n2 AND SIZE(friends1) = SIZE (friends2) AND ALL (f in friends1 WHERE f in friends2)
RETURN n1, n2
```

Comment: Thank You, this works very well.  I believe you can get the same result by taking out "AND SIZE(friends1) = SIZE (friends2)" and adding "AND ALL (f in friends2 WHERE f in friends1)" e.g. n1 has all friends of n2 and n2 has all friends of n1.

Comment: @pl80 You want the SIZE check. It filters out the case where friends1 is a subset of friends2, and if the SIZE check fails, Cypher can skip comparing the lists, which will save you a ton of dbhits.

Comment: good point.  Another issue I've run into is when I don't specify who n1 is, the database will run out of memory, as I have 30k relationships, so 30k square = 900M turns out too big for my machine.  Once I narrow down n1 to one Person, the query works quickly :)